# C# - if else in Data Annotations

Tags: c#, validation, if-statement, data-annotations

This is about Data Annotations in C#.

I have a class called MyClass. There I will be having two properties.

```
class MyClass
{
         private string _propName;
         public string PropName
         {
              get {return _propName;}
              set {_propName=value;}
         }

         private string _propVal;
         public string PropVal
         {
              get {return _propVal;}
              set {_propVal=value;}
         }
}
```

I have a MS SQl table which contains data for `propName` and relevant `propValue`.
I need to have validations using DataAnnotations. Each and every `_propName` need to have different validations.

My question is : How do I add different validations/data annotations to the class structure I have  mentioned above ? I was wondering whether or not there is some way to specify if-else conditions in Data Annotations ?

```
        if "this propertyname"
               validation 1
        else if "that property name"
               validation 1
```

Can someone help ?

Comment: you can always write your own data annotations attribute with your own logic.

Comment: Could you please give me an example ? Because I tried and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to something like this:

```
public class MyValidationAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        switch (validationContext.MemberName)
        {
            //some logic
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with `ValidationAttribute` your only going to get the value of the one property, not the combination of the properties, what you can do is combine the `PropName` and `PropVal` in a tuple, and then validate that.

This little test app shows a method of achieving what you want.

```
public class MyClass {
    [MyValidation]
    public Tuple<string, string> PropValue { get; set; }

    public List<ValidationResult> TestValidation() {
        var validationContext = new ValidationContext(this, serviceProvider: null, items: null);
        var results = new List<ValidationResult>();
        Validator.TryValidateObject(this, validationContext, results, validateAllProperties: true);

        return results;
    }
}

public class MyValidationAttribute : ValidationAttribute {
    public override bool IsValid(object value) {
        var propValue = value as Tuple<string, string>;

        if (propValue.Item1 == "Item") {
            var setPropValue = propValue.Item2;

            //Do you validation
        }

        return true;
    }
}


class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        MyClass instance = new MyClass();
        instance.PropValue = new Tuple<string, string>("Item", "Value");

        var result = instance.TestValidation();
    }
}
```